# Button is Not Working

Tags: android

I'm trying to add buttons to my activity. I can see the button but when pressing it nothing happens.
The code is below.

Thanks,
Nahum

Manifest.xml:

```
<Button android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Next"   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/w_button_next"></Button>
```

Java:

```
private Button b3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.wizard);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.w_button_next);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new NextClicked());


}
class NextClicked implements Button.OnClickListener {

 public void onClick(View v) {

       Context context = v.getContext();//getApplicationContext();
       CharSequence text = "On Click";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
       toast.show();
    GotoNextState();
}
}
```

Comment: I hope the xml file that has the button is named wizard.xml, not Manifest.xml. Is there anything in logcat when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your Context lookup. I always use a reference to the parent Activity (i.e. the enclosing class of your `NextClicked` inner class):

```
class ParentActivity extends Activity
{
    private Button b3;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.wizard);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.w_button_next);
        b3.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ParentActivity.this, "On Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                toast.show();
                GotoNextState();
            }
        });
    }
    private void GotoNextState() {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ParentActivity.this is not compiling. Beside, the method GotoNextState is not being called.

Comment: Well, there is no `GotoNextState()` method defined in my class which will explain why it doesn't compile, I was merely using it as an example of how to access the `Context` of the outer class using `ParentActivity.this`. Example updated so that it compiles.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I meant that the call to ParentActivity.this is not compiling

Comment: You'll need to change the name of it to match the name of your outer class, in my case this is `ParentActivity` but yours will be different. Your outer class must extend `Activity` or some other class which extends `Context`, if it doesn't, you'll have all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

i guess rather than implementing  Button.OnClickListener you can use View.OnClickListener

Comment: I think your button is getting pressed but its not showing any text in toast for someother reasons.... I 've used your code.. it's working fine here. Toast is also getting printed here..

Answer (score 0):

if you have a lot of buttons ,and you want to listen everyone , you implement the first solution , and if you have only one button , you can use the code of ***Mark Allison*** :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Button b3;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.wizard);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.w_button_next);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);


}
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

       CharSequence text = "On Click";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration);//i 've changed the context with :this
       toast.show();
    GotoNextState();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. OnClickListener is not compiling for me. It should View.OnClickListener or Button.OnClickListener. In both ways it is not working.

Comment: of course View.OnClickListener is the listener that you should use, if you are working on eclipse, try to use Ctrl+Space to complete the code when u are trying to code the listener.normally , the View.OnClickListener should works for u